# Jenkins Relational operators in groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to do a numerical comparison in Jenkins and perform a action based on that. `COUNT` is a string type parameter. But it is giving the below error.

```
WorkflowScript: 24: Expected a step @ line 24, column 14.
                if ( params.COUNT > 10 ) {
                ^
1 error
```

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label "${node_label}"
  }
  parameters {
    string(defaultValue: "1", description: "Number of VM's to be Added", name: "COUNT")
  }
  stages {
    stage('Parameter Validation') {
      steps {
             if ( params.COUNT > 10 ) {
             error("Instance count should be less than 10 and it is ${COUNT}")
        } 
      }
    }
    stage('Clone Latest Repo') {
      steps {
        echo "Pull latest code"
        build 'gitpull'
      }
  }
```

I tried different ways, but no luck

```
steps {
script {    
sh '''#!/bin/bash
if [[ "${COUNT}" -gt "10" ]]; then  
error("Instance count should be less than 10")
fi
'''
}
}
```

Comment: @DashrathMundkar I actually fixed the typo and still the same issue

Comment: You appear to be mixing [declarative and scripted ayntax](https://www.jenkins.iodoc/book/pipeline/#scripted-pipeline-fundamentals). [Try](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/) `when {
                      expression { COUNT > "10" }
                    }`

Comment: @lan W, I tried still no luck

Comment: Doh! Overlooked the string param and numeric comparator issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to typecast the string variable to INT `def intValue = COUNT as int`. This solution is working as desired

```
def intValue = COUNT as int
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Parameter Validation') {
      steps {
          script {
             if ( intValue > 10 ) {
             error("Instance count should be less than 10 and it is ${COUNT}")
            } 
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Clone Latest Repo') {
      steps {
        echo "Pull latest code"
        build 'gitpull'
      }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast the `string` param to `int` :

```
if (Integer.parseInt(params.COUNT) > 10)
{
   println ("Count > 10")
}
```

You complete pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label "${node_label}"
  }
  parameters {
    string(defaultValue: "1", description: "Number of VM's to be Added", name: "COUNT")
  }
  stages {
    stage('Parameter Validation') {
      steps {
             if ( Integer.parseInt(params.COUNT) > 10 ) {
             error("Instance count should be less than 10 and it is ${COUNT}")
        } 
      }
    }
    stage('Clone Latest Repo') {
      steps {
        echo "Pull latest code"
        build 'gitpull'
      }
  }
```